# when publish project it gave me error message computer using ram 4GB processor core i5

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

i am facing error message when i publish visual studio project it gave me the following message 
"problem generating manifest insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoX3r.jpg)
computer processor core i5
ram 4 GB 
and i switch off all unused services program from misconfig 
also i clean windows boot 
but invain it gave me the same message

Answer (score 1):

For the exception thrown by visual studio, please try the following steps to solve this issue:

1) You can first try resetting the Visual Studio setting, check out How to: Reset Your Settings.

2) Have you applied the latest service pack? If not, I suggest you apply the service pack.

3) If you reboot the operating system to safe mode, do you have the problem? This can help to isolate whether any other applications are interfering with Visual Studio. In addition to safe mode, you can also try “clean boot”.

If none of these solutions works,
This looks like faulty Visual Studio installation. So, try repairing it or remove and install the fresh one.